# How can I use python interpreter option "-O" on python executable file(exe)?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I made python exe file by pyinstaller using --onefile option.
And I want to use interpreter options like "-O" on my python exe file.
Because my python scripts include debug flags.

Below is simplification of my code structure.

```
# main.py
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lastIndex = len(sys.argv) - 1
    value1 = sys.argv[lastIndex-1]
    value2 = sys.argv[lastIndex]

    if __debug__:
        print('{} {}'.format(value1, value2))
```

I got main.exe using

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

I tried to execute main.exe with -O option on cmd, and it looks like debug flag wasn't affected by "-O"

```
> main.exe -O value1 value2
```

What can I do for this?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please post your code.

Comment: I just edited my post.

Comment: The [documentation on the pyinstaller website](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#running-pyinstaller-with-python-optimizations) implies to me that this is a decision you make when you build the exe. I'm not convinced there is a way to do what you want when you run the exe

Comment: @DavidW thank you so much !!! That documentation says what I need !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says

PyInstaller can be run with Python optimization flags (`-O` or `-OO`) by executing it as a Python module, rather than using the pyinstaller command:

```
# run with basic optimizations
python -O -m PyInstaller myscript.py 
# also discard docstrings
python -OO -m PyInstaller myscript.py
```

Or, by explicitly setting the `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable to a non-zero value.

Comment: Could you link to where in the documentation this is written?